# Check Internet connection with sockets

Tags: c

A small question: how can I use Linux sockets to check Internet connection, inside a C program? I heard that this one is the most simple and suitable method (instead of calling the program ping, for example), but I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it as you wish. :)

```
void *parser_online(void *garbage)
{
    int sockfd,val;
    char buffer[MAX_LINE];
    struct hostent *google_ent=NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in google_addr;

    sockfd = -1;

    if((google_ent = gethostbyname("www.google.com")) != NULL)
    {
        if((sockfd =    socket(google_ent->h_addrtype,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)) != -1)
        {
            val = 1;
            if(setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &val, sizeof(val)) == 0 && setsockopt(sockfd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &val, sizeof(val)) == 0)
            {
                google_addr.sin_family = google_ent->h_addrtype;
                memcpy(&(google_addr.sin_addr), google_ent->h_addr, google_ent->h_length);
                google_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
                if( connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &google_addr,sizeof(google_addr)) == 0)
                {
                    if(write(sockfd,"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n", 29) >= 28)
                    {
                        shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR);
                        if(read(sockfd, buffer, MAX_LINE) != -1) // all right!
                        {
                            close(sockfd);
                            return (void *) 1;
                        }
                        else
                            report_error("read()",1,0,verbose);
                    }
                    else
                        report_error("write()",1,0,verbose);
                }
                else
                    report_error("connect()",1,0,verbose);
            }
            else
                report_error("setsockopt()",1,0,verbose);
        }
        else
            report_error("socket()",1,0,verbose);
    }
    else
        report_error("cannot resolve IP for mom Google.",0,0,error); // this is is the most common error.

    if(sockfd!=-1)
        close(sockfd);
    return (void *) 0; // no internet

}
```

Comment: sorry....
I've forgot to tell you that you must include
sys/socket.h
netinet/tcp.h
netdb.h
netinet/in.h

I think that's all....if you have compiling errors just do:

`grep -nr "MISSING_MACRO" /usr/include`

Comment: ah! if you don't want to check HTTP but only internet status you can stop at the `connect()` call.

Comment: This code uses a hostname. It will be better to test an ip address like 8.8.8.8. To separate the case : connexion is broken from dns resolution is broken

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to a well known host (say google.com) on a well known open port, like 80.  If it fails there's a pretty good chance the internet is down. Here's a socket tutorial that will get you started: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm.

Comment: (Wasn't my downvote, still:) Maybe sloppy terminology? "The internet is down"? That's silly, as the Internet is never down (as a whole). Network engineers refer to such problems as "loss of network connectivity", "routing problems", "unreachable host/network/port" etc.